# What is the best way to cancel and handle errors in RXJS v6

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular-observable

```
import { fromEvent, interval, Subject, Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { takeUntil, switchMap, catchError } from "rxjs/operators";

const obs1 = p1 => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("obs1 doing");
      observer.next(p1 + "1");
      observer.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
};
const obs2 = p2 => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("obs2 doing");
      observer.next(p2 + "2");
      observer.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
};
const obs3 = p3 => {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("obs3 doing");
      observer.next(p3 + "3");
      observer.complete();
    }, 1000);
  });
};
const obsError1 = () => console.log("obs1 is error")
const obsError2 = () => console.log("obs2 is  error")
const obsError3 = () => console.log("obs3 is error")
const cancle = new Subject();

new Observable(observer => {
  obs1(0).subscribe(
    x1 => {
      obs2(x1).subscribe(
        x2 => {
          obs3(x2).subscribe(
            x3 => {
              observer.next(x3);
              observer.complete();
            },
            obsError3
          );
        },
        obsError2
      );
    },
    obsError1
  );
}).pipe(takeUntil(cancle)).subscribe(()=>{
  console.log()
});

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("cancle doing");
  cancle.next();
  cancle.complete();
}, 100);
```

When it run `cancle.next()`, it still prints  `obs2 doing` and `obs3 doing`

I know that changing to serial can be cancelled ,such as:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("cancle doing");
  cancle.next();
  cancle.complete();
}, 100);

of(0)
  .pipe(
    switchMap(x1 => obs1(x1)),
    catchError(error => {
      obsError1()
      throw error;
    })
  ).pipe(
    switchMap(x2 => obs2(x2)),
    catchError(error => {
      obsError2()
      throw error;
    })
  )
  .pipe(
    switchMap(x3 => obs3(x3)),
    catchError(error => {
      obsError3()
      throw error;
    })
  ).pipe(
    takeUntil(cancle)
  ).subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

But when an error occurs in obs1, `obsError2` will also be executed

I do n’t know the best way to handle errors

all code is in https://stackblitz.com/edit/mbqhrs

Comment: that's because you throw in obsError1, if you return of() it'll carry on to stream 2 without throwing.

Comment: if I don't throw error ,it will run obs2

Comment: ya that's the expected behavior, what exactly you want to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle and error in a stream you need to use `catchError` operator.
It accepts an error, if you are able to handle the error - simply return new stream, if the error should be passes further - simply throw it again.

```js
o$.pipe(
 catchError(error => {
   if (error.message === 'i can handle it') {
      return of('value we want to pass');
   }
   if (error.message === 'i can handle it 2') {
      return EMPTY; // simply completes the stream without an emit.
   }
   throw error; // i don't know what to do with such an error.
 }),
).subscribe(console.log); // can receive 'i can handle it'.
```

Comment: I'm so sorry to be back after a long time.  I abstract my needs. My needs will be calculated in 3 steps. When the first step is wrong, the page displays "First Step Error". When an error occurs in the second step, the page displays "Second Step Error". In addition, the user can click the button to cancel all calculations.

Comment: Every step of my calculation is a promise. As we all know, the implementation of canceling promises is not elegant, so I want to use rxjs outside of the promises calculated at each step.